# Memory optimized OrderBy and Take?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, memory, out-of-memory

I have 9 GB of data, and I want only 10 rows. When I do:

```
 data.OrderBy(datum => datum.Column1)
     .Take(10)
     .ToArray();
```

I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. I would like to use an `OrderByAndTake` method, optimized for lower memory consumption. It's easy to write, but I guess someone already did. Where can I find it.

**Edit**: It's Linq-to-objects. The data comes from a file. Each row can be discarded if its value for `Column1` is smaller than the current list of 10 biggest values.

Comment: Is this Linq to Objects or an ORM?

Comment: @Henk answered in the last edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this in Linq to Objects. You could do something like...

```
var best = data
    .Aggregate(new List<T>(), (soFar, current) => soFar
                                                 .Concat(new [] { current })
                                                 .OrderBy(datum => datum.Column1)
                                                 .Take(10)
                                                 .ToList());
```

In this way, not all the items need to be kept in a new sorted collection, only the best 10 you're interested in.

This was the least code way. Since you know the `soFar` list is sorted, testing where/if to insert `current` could be optimized. I didn't feel like doing ALL the work for you. ;-)

PS: Replace `T` with whatever your type is.

EDIT: Thinking about it, the most efficient way would actually be a plain old `foreach` that compares each item to the running list of best 10.

Comment: Your first solution works, but it is 40x slower than `OrderBy().Take()`. I implemented your suggestions and the resulting code is 10x faster than `OrderBy().Take()`

Answer (score 2):

It figures: OrderBy is a Sort and that requires storing all the elements (deferred execution is cancelled).

It ought to work efficiently when `data` is an IQueryable, then it's up to the database.

---

```
  // just 4 fun
  public static IEnumerable<T> TakeDistinctMin<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, 
        int n, Func<T, TKey> selector)            
         where TKey: IComparable<TKey>
  {
        var tops = new SortedList<TKey, T>(n+1);

        foreach (var item in @this)
        {
            TKey k = selector(item);

            if (tops.ContainsKey(k))
                continue;

            if (tops.Count < n)
            {
                tops.Add(k, item);
            }
            else if (k.CompareTo(tops.Keys[tops.Count - 1]) < 0)
            {
                tops.Add(k, item);
                tops.RemoveAt(n);
            }                                    
        }

        return tops.Values;
    }
```

Comment: I know they require it. But it is simple to write a `OrderByAndTake` that doesn't need that. In my case I don't use databases.

Comment: I would suggest another name:  `TakeMax(int n)`, that avoid the suggestion of sorting them all. And you're right, this is a straight-forward programming exercise: Find the largest|smallest N elements in one scan.

Comment: I posted a solution. You can have some tips for me, if you review it.

Comment: Note that this version has a built-in Distinct(), that may be OK or not.

Comment: This is `O(n*@this.Count())`. So this is OK for the OPs 10 rows, but not good as a general purpose implementation.

Comment: @code: that's the worst-case, in practice the `if(... < 0) ` will make it approach O(Count), even for a much larger `n`. As long as n << Count.

Comment: If you list is sorted descending in your key I think that already hits the worst case

Comment: I tested it against `OrderBy().Take()` and your version is 9x faster. But it doesn't produces the same results, since it has a `Distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

To order a set of unordered objects you have to look at all of them, no?

I don't see how you'd be able to avoid parsing all 9 GB of data to get the first 10 ordered in a certain way unless the 9 GB of data was already ordered in that fashion or if there were indexes or other ancillary data structures that could be utilized.

Could you provide a bit more background on your question. Are you querying a database using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or some other O/RM?

Comment: You have to iterate over all of them, but you don't need to have them all in memory at the same time.

Comment: I don't intend to avoid parsing them. I don't use ORM nor databases in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this together with a [projection comparer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderAndTake<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq,int count,IComparer<T> comp)
{
  var resultSet=new SortedSet<T>(comp);
  foreach(T elem in seq)
  {
    resultSet.Add(elem);
    if(resultSet.Count>count)
        resultSet.Remove(resultSet.Max);
  }
  return resultSet.Select(x=>x);
}
```

Runtime should be `O(log(count)*seq.Count())` and space `O(min(log(count),seq.Count()))`

One issue is that it will break if you have two elements for which `comp.Compare(a,b)==0` since the set doesn't allow duplicate entries.

Comment: The need for a projection comparer makes this implementation a bit annoying.

Comment: Note that this also has an implied Distinct(). The results could differ from the original.

Comment: @Henk That's the issue I mentioned in my last sentence.

Comment: I tested your solution and is 3x faster than `OrderBy().Take()`. But it has 2 drawbacks, it doesn't support a key selector as `OrderBy` does, and it doesn't allow duplicate entries.

Comment: The first drawback can be worked around using a projection comparer like in the blog I linked. The second one probably needs a compound key build from the selected key and the number an item had in the sequence(which results in a stable sort as a side effect).